# C++: How to install OpenCV with the compiler MinGW 9.2.0 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a few days ago trying to install opencv using Dev-Cpp and Windows 10, i add the directories of the .h, .lib and .dll files to the Dev-Cpp, but when i compile the code always give me the same error.

In compiler options i add the next directories:

-C++ Headers--

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\include`

-Libraries-

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib`

-Binary files-

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin`

-Code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main(){
    cv::Mat img;
    img = cv::imread("Goten.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

-Errors-

```
c:\mingw\mingw32\bin\ld.exe C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cciHfDkS.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
c:\mingw\mingw32\bin\ld.exe C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cciHfDkS.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
c:\mingw\mingw32\bin\ld.exe C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cciHfDkS.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[__ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x40): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
c:\mingw\mingw32\bin\ld.exe C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cciHfDkS.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MataSEOS0_[__ZN2cv3MataSEOS0_]+0xb4): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Programacion\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed MinGW 9.2.0, i tried compile it with the standards C++11, C++14 and C++17

**What can i do to fix this error?** - Sorry for my english

Comment: Dev-C++ hasn't been updated in more than 5 years. Do yourself a favor and move on to another IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are linker errors: it means the compiler can't find the binary code for those functions.

In other words, you might have forgotten to specify a few OpenCV libraries. If I'm not mistaken, `imread()` resides in **opencv_imgcodecs**.

Answer (score 0):

Does vcpkg on Windows require VisualStudio, or does it also work with MinGW?  (Doing a very quick Google search seems to show it might work.)  Cause ever since I discovered `vcpkg`, I must admit that I'd never go back to installing and building things the old way.

Now, to get almost anything on windows, I'd [clone the vcpkg repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/), run the bootstrap script, and then run `vcpkg.exe install opencv`.

Comment: that give me an error because i'm using dev-cpp and not visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a good source code editor (perhaps [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) and compile on the command line (e.g. by using a build automation tool such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) in a terminal emulator.

Then MinGW is actually some command with `g++` or `g++.exe`

Then you just can download the *source code* of [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) and compile it in some terminal emulator. Or even better, get the [source code from github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.3.0). The compilation of OpenCV from source code could last a dozen of minutes or an hour of computer time/

BTW, if you really are interested in programming OpenCV, I recommend installing a Linux distribution (e.g. [Debian](https://debian.org/)). Most GNU/Linux systems have a genuine and recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), not just an emulation of GCC called MinGW.